# bufferedreader - read into stringbuffer and not string

Tags: java, stream, while-loop, bufferedreader, stringbuffer

I have the following code.  What I would like to do is read each line from the BufferedReader directly into a StringBuffer to reduce memory overhead.  Once it gets to the end of the data stream I would like it to exit the while loop.

```
StringBuffer line = new StringBuffer();
        URL url = new URL("a url");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                int count = 0;
                while(line.append(reader.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.println(line.toString());
                    line.delete(0,line.length());
                }
```

It reads the stream fine but when I get to the end of the stream it returns null and keeps printing null without exiting the loop.  Any

Comment: I think that use `for(String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) { ... }` only create references.

Comment: Why are you reading into a `StringBuffer` only to delete it after printing out the line. Why not just print the line directly out?

Comment: Q. How can the result of append() ever be null? A. It can't.

Answer (score 4):

This `while(line.append(reader.readLine()) != null)` is basically the same as saying `while(line.append(reader.readLine()).toString() != null)` which is never likely to happen.

The other problem you might have, is `null` is actually being translated to a literal `String` of `"null"`.  That's why it's printing "null", the value isn't actually `null` - confused yet...

Instead, try something like...

```
String text = null;
while((text = reader.readLine()) != null){
    line.append(text)
    System.out.println(line.toString());
    line.delete(0,line.length());
}
```

**Updated**

While I'm here, I might suggest that you are actually not saving your self anything.

`readLine` will create `String` object, which you're putting into a `StringBuffer`.  You're not actually saving any memory, but rather complicating the process.

If you're really worried about creating lots of `String` objects in memory, then use `BufferedReader#read(char[])` instead.  Append the resulting character array to the `StringBuffer`.

Also, unless you need synchronized access to the `StringBuffer`, use `StringBuilder` instead, it's faster.

Comment: I am reading into a stringbuffer and the using split(",") which goes into an array. I could be reading up to and more than a 1000 lines so I would like to keep memory usage down. But I'll try the char suggestion.

Comment: You have to realize the `reader.readLine()` has already create a `String` object, so any benefit you think you're getting from using a `StringBuffer` is negotiable.  Having said that `String = String + String` ends up creating one additional String object per concatenation (I think 3 in that example), so you are saving your self a little

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly.  You just have to catch the NUllPointerException

```
while(line.append(reader.readLine().toString()) != null){
```

Comment: Does it, as far as I'm, aware, `StringBuffer` will convert the `null` value to a `String` literal of "null"

Comment: That's weird, cause `System.out.println(new StringBuffer().append((String)null).toString() == null)` returns `false` for me

Comment: Actually, now I read it :P, reader.readLine().toString() would raise a NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

You could try the same with this for-loop:

```
for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
    System.out.println(line); // Or whatever
}
```